# Porting a GUI from a pc to a wince device - issue is with the size of the screen

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, resources

I have to port a GUI that is currently running on a pc, to a wince device. I have already compiled the code on a win CE platform, the problem is now with the size of the screen of the device which is smaller than some of the dialog boxes of the GUI. I could resize some them in resource view of visual studio 2005. I am unable to proceed further as a lot of screens have bitmaps mapped to them and i cannot just resize the dialog boxes without changing the corresponding bitmaps.
What is the best way to proceed- my last resort would be to disable the bitmaps and redraw them at a later stage. 
is there some method of automatically mapping the size of the screen to all the dialog boxes so that they would automatically resize (alongwith the assocaiated buttons etc)

Answer (score 3):

Honestly I think my advise would be to stop and think about the differences between the two contexts before event considering how you would scale the interfaces.

PCs and phones have completely different interaction paradigms and simply scaling from a PC to a phone is very unlikely to work. Even if you could, it's likely to produce an unsatisfactory user experience.

I would expect that the best way to proceed is to sit down and draft up a new UI for the phones. Then bring you back ground code across from the PC and code up the interface part to work with the new UI. If you code is designed according to MVC principles then you are just looking at recoding the controllers and redesigning the views.

Comment: The application is not for a phone but for a chip that can support stuff from streaming radio to bluetooth and audio files support. The existing UI has over 150 source files and it would be better if i could reuse it by overcoming just the difference in scale. the LCD screen has touch interface enabled and hence all the functionality of the GUI is supported.